# Columns don't appear before going to TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I making program in wpf that use database and bind value to datagrid. I have two TabControl, and datagrid exist in second. I want to fill it after window loaded and make first column invisible. But although after fill there are items but no columns before select second tab. Why it so?

This is my xaml code

```
 <Window x:Class="AdminControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdminControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="513.5" Width="994" Loaded="MainWindowLoaded">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_BarCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Артикул" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="32,28,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Название" Width="120" Margin="185,28,0,191"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Price" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Цена" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="185,114,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Keywords" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ключевые слова" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="32,114,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_TabTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Заголовок вкладки" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="823,69,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Description_Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Заголовок Описания" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="658,69,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Link" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ССылка" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="494,69,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Length" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Длина" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="32,69,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Height" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Высота" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="823,28,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Width" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ширина" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="658,28,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Weight" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Вес" Width="120" Margin="494,28,0,433"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Count" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Количество" Width="120" Margin="337,28,0,191"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Название изображения" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Margin="337,114,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Описание" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="185,69,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Product_SearchDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Описание Поисковика" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="337,69,0,0"/>

                <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid x:Name="categoryGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="875,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="388" Width="91" InitializingNewItem="categoryGridAddRow" IsEnabled="True"/>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="464" Width="860" Margin="10,10,0,-22" Grid.Column="0" Initialized="sadfasd"/>
                <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" Margin="903,422,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button1_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I believe the tab control's visual tree only renders when the tab becomes active. This is why the columns are not there yet